# Magento Field dependency on multiple radio buttons

Tags: magento, field

I want to show/hide radio buttons. Using field dependency i can hide/show field if its select,textbox,text,textarea etc... but when i used for `multiple radio buttons` which has same name but different IDs then its not working.

Please find attached images as well here right now you can see list of radio buttons i want to hide those when select other option from above select box.

[image]

Can you please suggest what to do? Waiting for Answer.

Comment: did you want to restrict some radio buttons, depends on the selection on the select box?

Comment: I want to hide/show this radio button list onchange `Type` Select box event

Comment: You can say something like this hide/show radio buttons onchange event of Selectbox.

Comment: you can simply do it with javascript. wait i'm preparing fiddle demo.

Comment: yes i have this idea as well but i want to do using addField and addFieldDependence magento functions? can i do using this one?

Comment: My point is that if we can use addFieldDependence for one field then can't we use same for multiple radio buttons?

Comment: you mean, to add same dependancy method for multiple attribute(radio buttons)?

Comment: Yes right i want to do something like this.

Comment: If i found answer regarding this then it will works for me as well. is there any way to add custom field with div at magento backend?So i can hide/show this div. For example `<div id="radiogroup">Radion button list</div>`

Comment: are you working with Dependent Custom Options magento extension?

Comment: No i am working on one custom extention in that i want to hide/show `Radio button list` onchange event of `SelectBox`

Comment: I think, you have clear idea about this concept. But i can't help you with out seeing your code. If you change core code of that extension, may be that functionality will be fail. I think, you can use simple jQuery method for those attributes. It works with all tag, not only for <div>

Comment: Actually i didn't idea how to put this radio buttons in div with `addField` method. I want something like `Recurring Profile` option in product. when we select "Yes" then below "Recurring Payment Profile" come when select "No" then that div is hide.

Comment: Hi i can hide/show radio button list using my jQuery code but can you please suggest how to add field with DIV? Please give me answer if you have this will great help for me.

Comment: I found solution using my way i use jQuery with parent tr,td and hide/show accordingly. Anyways thank you all.